# Debugging tips for errors after optimization

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, memory

I'm working with some very old C++ code that was originally written in C back in the DOS days. I'll save you the details, but it's filled with proudly optimized mathematical equations and hacks and esoteric pointer math that make it very complicated to follow.

The code in question looks like this:

```
while (not_finished) {
    // Lots of stuff.

    // Compute velocity for this time step
    double scaled_position[4] = {};
    double prev_scaled_position[4];
    double velocity[4] = {};

    scaled_position[0] = a + b * c;  // some equation here.
    velocity[0] = scaled_position[0] - prev_scaled_position[0];
    prev_scaled_position[0] = scaled_position[0];

    // Compute other indexes.
    // Write velocity to a file
}
```

What's happening is that `velocity[0]` is always zero (not any other index, just `[0]`!), because `prev_scaled_position[0]` seems to be always the same value as `scaled_position[0]`, even though I can't even imagine how this can happen.

The following are weird points:

1. I've tried initializing the arrays to zero, but if I add (e.g.) `double scaled_position[4] = {}`, the `velocity[0]` is always zero, as if it's re-setting it to zero with every loop. That's not the way this variable initialization should behave, right? Shouldn't it just do this once??
2. If I move `double scaled_position[4] = {}` to the top of the file (global initialization), it all works fine. But I assume there's a change in the memory layout that makes the bug just not show itself.
3. Changing the compiler optimization level from "on" (`-O1` through `-O3`) back to "off" (`-O0`) makes everything work perfectly well.
4. I've tried setting a watch point on `prev_scaled_position[0]`, and it's never triggered when I don't expect it to be.

This is either a very stupid issue, or a very complex one, and I'm struggling to debug this further. What would you look at next? What tools would you use to understand this better?

Comment: Are you missing a `;` after `prev_scaled_position[0] = scaled_position[0]`?

Comment: `double prev_scaled_position[4];` -- This is uninitialized, but you use it as if it is initialized.

Comment: "_That's not the way this variable initialization should behave, right? Shouldn't it just do this once??_": The variable is declared inside the loop body. The array exists only for one loop iteration. Each time the loop iterates you have a completely new instance of the array. Each of these instances should of course be initialized by the initializer on the variable declaration.

Comment: It would seem as though you are accessing something out of bounds and writing over the variable in question. Tools like AddressSanitizer can help find issues like this, but often not if the place where you overflow writes into a different valid variable space. To make it effective you may need to move things around to isolate the issue.

Comment: Debugging optimized code is a <expletive deleted> because the optimizer's allowed to make any and all transformations to the code that (mostly-see copy elision) don't change the program behaviour and effectively sends the program through a blender.   Turn on sanitizers where possible and let them find what they can.

Comment: It is honestly not clear what issue exactly you are trying to find with the debugger. It is pretty clear that you are accessing `prev_scaled_position` uninitialized and you seem to have some misunderstanding of how variable scoping works from what I can gather from your code and questions (?). Maybe try to present a complete [mre] and more detailed explanation of what problem you see.

Comment: If `prev_scaled_position[0] == scaled_positio[0]` then `velocity[0]` will be zero.

Comment: Okay, you are all correct about your points, but this is pseudocode. I missed a semicolon and `prev_scaled_position[4]` is uninitialized, but it's not in the actual code.

Comment: But I think the point @user17732522 makes about variables only lasting for one loop iteration is potentially the key issue... I'll research this a bit. Maybe I've been getting lucky in the past 15 years, and I really misunderstood something about how scoped variables are declared. I don't really see how this could affect only index 0.

Comment: @user17732522, you seem to have found the obvious issue. Thank you. I'm astonished I didn't realize this behavior years ago. I thought the compiler was smart enough to maintain the memory allocation for variables scoped like this.

Comment: Compiler is smart enough, actually it would be somewhat easier, but it deliberately doesn't because of the language's scoping rules. This is one of the nasties because sometimes, and maybe a lot of the time, you'll get exactly the behaviour you're expecting simply because it is easier and cheaper to just leave the memory alone. But you get absolutely no guarantees. Such is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).